# Failed to create table in html from api data using ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I need help on how to create table from data fetch from API server in html.

A possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224584/adding-data-rows-dynamically-from-a-json-object-using-javascript)

I need to request json data from a url, then use that data to dynamically create table in html.

Below are my `test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
...
</head>
<body>
...
...
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Activity</h3>
            </div>
            <div id = "showData" class="box-body"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<script src="../static/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:4220/pipeline/v1/bpwi/",
    success: function (data) {
      var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in data[i]) {
          if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            col.push(key);
          }
        }
      }

      var table = document.createElement("table");

      var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }
      }

      var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected `ajax` response is something like this

```
[
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Name": "Computer",
            "Category": "Computers",
            "Price": "125.60"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "Blue",
            "Category": "Sport",
            "Price": "56.00"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Book Name": "Science",
            "Category": "Science",
            "Price": "210.40"
        }
    ]
```

I have refreshed my browser many times but the result is not good.

Here is the result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Activity
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0
[
{
"
I
D
"
:
"
1
"
...
...
```

I am really new to javascript and some of good example I found is the possible question I posted above and [here](http://www.encodedna.com/javascript/populate-json-data-to-html-table-using-javascript.htm) but both did not show a clear example on how to implement `http request` for getting the data from external source.

I really hope someone can pointed out for me what I did wrong in this code.
Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: why didnt you define in ajax parameters `dataType` and `type`?

Comment: right!!...thank you. Your suggestion helped me